# Copy file in Java and replace existing target

Tags: java, file, replace, copy

I'm trying to copy a file with java.nio.file.Files like this:

```
Files.copy(cfgFilePath, strTarget, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

The problem is that Eclipse says "The method copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (File, String, StandardCopyOption)"

I'm using Eclipse and Java 7 on Win7 x64. My project is set up to use Java 1.6 compatibility.

Is there a solution to this or do I have to create something like this as a workaround:

```
File temp = new File(target);

if(temp.exists())
  temp.delete();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a complement to @assylias' answer:

If you use Java 7, drop `File` entirely. What you want is `Path` instead.

And to get a `Path` object matching a path on your filesystem, you do:

```
Paths.get("path/to/file"); // argument may also be absolute
```

Get used to it real fast. Note that if you still use APIs which require `File`, `Path` has a `.toFile()` method.

Note that if you are in the unfortunate case where you use an API which returns `File` objects, you can always do:

```
theFileObject.toPath()
```

But in code of yours, use `Path`. Systematically. Without a second thought.

**EDIT** Copying a file to another using 1.6 using NIO can be done as such; note that the `Closer` class is inspited by [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html):

```
public final class Closer
    implements Closeable
{
    private final List<Closeable> closeables = new ArrayList<Closeable>();

    // @Nullable is a JSR 305 annotation
    public <T extends Closeable> T add(@Nullable final T closeable)
    {
        closeables.add(closeable);
        return closeable;
    }

    public void closeQuietly()
    {
        try {
            close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
        throws IOException
    {
        IOException toThrow = null;
        final List<Closeable> l = new ArrayList<Closeable>(closeables);
        Collections.reverse(l);

        for (final Closeable closeable: l) {
            if (closeable == null)
                continue;
            try {
                closeable.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (toThrow == null)
                    toThrow = e;
            }
        }

        if (toThrow != null)
            throw toThrow;
    }
}

// Copy one file to another using NIO
public static void doCopy(final File source, final File destination)
    throws IOException
{
    final Closer closer = new Closer();
    final RandomAccessFile src, dst;
    final FileChannel in, out;

    try {
        src = closer.add(new RandomAccessFile(source.getCanonicalFile(), "r");
        dst = closer.add(new RandomAccessFile(destination.getCanonicalFile(), "rw");
        in = closer.add(src.getChannel());
        out = closer.add(dst.getChannel());
        in.transferTo(0L, in.size(), out);
        out.force(false);
    } finally {
        closer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this will work when I compile with compliance level for Java 1.6 as mentioned, but in any case thanks for the note, will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: @commander_keen do you mean the code you will deploy to runs 1.6 JVMs?

Comment: That is correct. As now recognized in the comments above, the whole Path thing and copy methods won't work. :-( Have to figure out how to copy files with Java 1.6 methods only and implement it again. Hints on best practice for 1.6 are welcome, though.

Comment: [File**s**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) != [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). File**s** is part of nio. Please don't write 60 lines of boilerplate to avoid using Files.copy.

Comment: @suriv the OP says he has to use Java 6... And yes, I know JSR 203. Quite well in fact.

Answer (score 129):

You need to pass `Path` arguments as explained by the error message:

```
Path from = cfgFilePath.toPath(); //convert from File to Path
Path to = Paths.get(strTarget); //convert from String to Path
Files.copy(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

That assumes your `strTarget` is a valid path.

Comment: Arg, why did I think it was an issue with the copyOption... Totally ignored the first two parameter types, thank you. Seems like I've been coding for too long in the heat. ;-)

Comment: Uff, after copying the exported jar to a PC with Java 1.6 (that's why I mentioned that I need to be 1.6 compatible although I develop with Java 7 and compile for 1.6), it moans 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.File.toPath()Lja
va/nio/file/Path;"

according to the documentations it's right, this method is only available since Java 7. (I wonder why this was not critized during development/design-time like other things I tried to use from Java 7 before, now I have to check everything by hand...)

Comment: I have one query about this :  if two persons are uploading a image which **name and type** is same but image is different then who will upload in last with same type then previous image will replace with new image which has same type. what should i do for this **problem** because type and name is same but image is different so I don't want to replace it.

Comment: @VikasRoy I suggest you ask a separate question explaining your specific issue.

Answer (score 7):

```
package main.java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class CopyFileOnExist {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Path sourceDirectory = Paths.get("C:/Users/abc/Downloads/FileNotFoundExceptionExample/append.txt");
        Path targetDirectory = Paths.get("C:/Users/abc/Downloads/FileNotFoundExceptionExample/append5.txt");

        //copy source to target using Files Class
        try {
            Files.copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

strTarget is a "String" object and not a "Path" object

Answer (score 0):

your statement Files.copy(path,Stringor address,StandardCopyOption) is this While you are giving a String where you have to set path of where you want to save file.
So simple Use this statement below:-

Files.copy(path,Paths.get(String or address),StandardCopyOption) by using Paths.get converts String into File location or path source path where you have to save file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).