# How to append a line in a file or before encountering newline character?

Tags: java, file

**Input File:**

```
Online_system_id
bank_details
payee
credit_limit
loan_amount

Online_system_id
bank_details
payee
credit_limit
loan_amount
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Online_syatem_id
bank_details
payee
credit_limit
loan_amount
proc_online_system_id

Online_syatem_id
bank_details
payee
credit_limit
loan_amount
proc_online_system_id
```

Below is the code given for reference.
I want to add a line after each record i.e before encountering the blank line.
What changes do I need to do?

```
String line;
int flag=0;
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(outputFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outputFile));
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    if(!line.contains("proc_online_system_id")){
        flag=1;                 
    }

}
if(flag==1)
    out.print("proc_online_system_id");
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String line;
PrintStream out = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
  out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)); 
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)); 
  while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    if(line.trim().isEmpty()) {            
        out.println("proc_online_system_id");   //print what you want here, BEFORE printing the current line         
    }
    out.println(line);        //always print the current line
  }

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
} finally { 
  try{
    out.close(); 
    br.close();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
  }
}
```

And don't forget the `out.close();` and `br.close();` afterwards.
This solution stores only the current line in memory, as opposed to [Dakkaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30780592/2516301), which is correct, but needs to store the whole file in memory (in a StringBuilder instance), before writing to file.

EDIT: After Vixen's comment, [here is the link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), in case you have java 7, and you want to use try with resources in your solution.

Comment: your code is not working. It appends the line at the end of file

Comment: could use try with resources if java7 or later

Comment: @vefthym you updated answer runs the code in infinite loop without append anything in the file.

Comment: @user3678383 I am sorry, you are right. It should work now, but using a new file as output.

Comment: @vefthym how can I replace the input file with output file?

Comment: @user3678383 I'm glad that it finally worked! To replace an old file, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17169576/2516301

Comment: @vefthym Thanks a lott. I want some more help from you. I am updating the question kindly go through it.

Comment: @user3678383 I think you should rollback to the previous question and make the updated one, a new question. This way, someone with the previous question will know the solution and someone with the new question will see any new answer.

Comment: You should nest two `try {} finally {}` to close both resources no matter what fails. If `out.close()` fails `br` in will remain open. It won't happen but there is a chance. You may use try-with-resources too.

Comment: @user3678383 I did that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
String line;
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(outputFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outputFile));
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
   if (!line.trim().isEmpty()){
      line+="\n";
    }
   //System.out.println(line);       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buffer each block. So what you do is read the file line by line and store the content of the current block in a StringBuilder. When you encounter the empty line, append your additional data. When you did that with the whole file, write the content of the StringBuilder to the file.

```
String line;
int flag=0;
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(outputFile);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outputFile));
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    if(!line.contains("proc_online_system_id")){
         flag=1;                
    }
    if (line.isEmpty() && flag==1) {
        flag=0;
        builder.append("proc_online_system_id\n");
    }
    builder.append(line).append("\n");
}
out.print(builder.toString());
```

Comment: Can do, give me a second

Comment: Try that. I didn't test it (currently not on a system with a Java SDK) but it should work.

Comment: @Dakkron not getting required output. It stores only current line. I want to store whole file