# Copying files with Java

Tags: java

I'm attempting to copy a file from one location to another while replacing the older file and I keep getting this error:
`The method copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (File, File, StandardCopyOption)`

My code is as follows

```
Files.copy(file1, file2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

I've also tried using this method:

```
CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
  StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
}; 
Files.copy(file1, file2, options[0]);
```

And I get this error: `The method copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (File, File, CopyOption)`

Any thoughts?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, I'd say: You need to provide a Path object instead of a FIle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `Path` objects, not `File`s:

```
Files.copy(file1.toPath(), file2.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: ...... Yup, that's what I get for not reading the whole error message. I was just assuming that the issue was the StandardCopyOption

Comment: The last parameter is a varargs parameter, which allows you to pass a single `CopyOption`.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the helpful error message, `file1` and `file2` are `File` objects.

But you need to pass `Path` objects to the `copy` method.

So you need to use

`Files.copy(file1.toPath(), file2.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You Should not use Files. Instead of that use paths.

```
Files.copy(file1.toPath(), file2.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried casting the StandardCopyOption?
Try:

```
    CopyOption co = (CopyOption) StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;
```

Based on the error you are getting, it seems to me that you are using files even though the method Files.copy() uses Inputstream or Path, not Files.

This may be a duplicate of [Copy file in Java and replace existing target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169541/copy-file-in-java-and-replace-existing-target)

Hope this helps. Good Luck Have Fun :)