# copying all files in a directory to another directory is not working

Tags: java, file, io

public class test {

```
private static void copyGABuild(){
     try {
         String loc = "C:\\Users\\KAG\\Desktop\\\\test";
         
         Files.copy(Paths.get(loc), Paths.get("C:\\Users\\KAG\\Desktop"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    copyGABuild();
```

}

I am getting this error 'java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException' C:\Users\KAG\Desktop

I dont want to use FileUtils to copy, is there any way I can achieve this using Files.
And there is no file inside the directory C:\Users\KAG\Desktop. but it still says FileAlreadyExistsException

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721668/files-move-and-files-copy-is-throwing-java-nio-file-filealreadyexistsexception) link, the `copy` method accepts a REPLACE_EXISTING parameter, which solves your problem.

You can implement this as follows:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(loc), Paths.get("C:\\Users\\KAG\\Desktop"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

Give this a shot!

**EDIT:**

See [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048662/copying-all-files-in-a-directory-to-another-directory-is-not-working/66048730#66048730):

> REPLACE_EXISTING – Performs the copy even when the target file already exists. If the target is a symbolic link, the link itself is copied (and not the target of the link). If the target is a non-empty directory, the copy fails with the FileAlreadyExistsException exception.

I left a comment for your problem, if this is the case. Good luck!

Comment: there is no file inside  C:\Users\KAG\Desktop, but it still saying file exists

Comment: is C:\Users\KAG\Desktop empty?, if so can you create a dummy file inside it, and rerun your code? Does it run succesfully now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Files.copy` is specified as unambiguous as possible.
Hence you need to specify the target to be created/overwritten.

For a file that would be:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(loc), Paths.get("C:\\Users\\KAG\\Desktop\\test"));
```

The mistake: a directory is copied without content! Javadoc:

> If the file is a directory then it creates an empty directory in the target location

> This method can be used with the walkFileTree method to copy a directory and all entries in the directory, or an entire file-tree where required.

However `Files` also has Stream methods for directory walks. Take care to createDirectories of subdirectories.