# Is there a way to replace an html file with another one by coding in Java?

Tags: java

My purpose is to replace an html file in a folder by another one, so that at the end :

`html_link1` will be replaced by `html_link2`

Is there a way to update HTML files by executing code in Java ?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Path sourceDirectory = Paths.get("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/project/adresse.url");
    Path targetDirectory = Paths.get("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/project/adresse2.url");

    //copy source to target using Files Class
    try {
        Files.copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

I need to find a way to change the URL, since the Path are now the same, the URL of the second HTML file didn't changed

Comment: Imagine you have an txt file where you write html code. Now save it as html.

Comment: Look at the [java.nio.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) class and it's application.

Comment: Here's a solution to replacing files in java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17169576/7091644

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the absolute file path untill and unless you wish to replace the whole directory.

```
Path sourceFilePath = Paths.get("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/project/adresse.url");
Path targetFilePath = Paths.get("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/project/adresse2.url");

try {
    Files.copy(sourceFilePath , targetFilePath ,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me but now I have to change the url of the 2nd adress, since now only the path change and not the url

Answer (score -1):

So long as they actually files, and you have the proper permission for the directory they are in, then you can do this the same way you would for any file.